# How do I change the view behind the popup after an ajax post?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an "Edit Profile" lightbox on my page, which posts to the controller via jQuery ajax. I handle the response in the jquery end instead of returning a View.  However, when the profile is saved, I need to refresh the values on the page displaying the popup.  How could I achieve this in MVC2?  For example, if the user changes her name and avatar (in the lightbox), after she saves the profile, I'd like to update the avatar and name everywhere it occurs on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Well what i would be doing is make your Controller return a **PartialViewResult**, which the end result is basically HTML.

The Partial View would be the popup itself, so essentially your calling your Controller method via AJAX, doing your server-side work, then re-rendering the Partial View to the client.

Comment: Thanks, so I need to update teh values not only in the popup, but also in the background page (even though it's darker, you can still see the old values).  So would I be following @jim's method of returning two partial viewss (one for the popup and one for the page containing the popup)?

Comment: Yes, the best way to asychnously update portions of the page is using PartialViewResults with AJAX. This is the closest thing we have in MVC to the UpdatePanel control in Web Forms.

Comment: Actually what I need to update is the page containing the popup, not the popup itself...

Comment: @Prabhu - the **whole page**? Or just portions of it?

Comment: @RPM1984--just portions of it--wherever the updated information is seen (for example, the name).

Comment: @Prabhu - if it's just a few fields, then i'd recommend doing an AJAX call (via jQuery) to a controller method which returns `JsonResult` containing the updated info. Then simply update the page. If there is say > 5 fields, then wrap those fields in a partial view and make the action method return a partial view result.

Answer (score 0):

Have the action you post to via jQuery return a `success` for `failure` message. If it is a `success`, change the avatar/name/etc on the page using the values already in the textboxes (i.e.: the values you posted to the controller). If it is a `failure` message, display the validation errors.

In your jQuery AJAX, everything can be done in the callback function of the AJAX request.

Comment: so basically replace the page values manually by manipulating the dom with the updated values? I was thinking of that, but was wondering if that's the best standard practice.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I'm not sure a `best standard practice` exists for this specific scenario, but the method I detailed is simple and efficient; I don't see any downsides to using it.

Comment: The "best standard practice" in ASP.NET MVC is RPM1984's answer. But this approach works just the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066383/how-do-i-change-the-view-behind-the-popup-after-an-ajax-post/4066578#4066578

Answer (score 0):

Prabhu - both your profile page (i.e. the 'main' div contained within it) and the popup div should be partialviews. on posting the popup back to the server, you should requery the main page partialview and return the appropriate html, targetting the 'main' div.

that's certainly the approach that i take for a very similar task.